# error accessing the columns of a json output using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a json output from an API like this

```
 {'trainingInput': 
  {'pythonModule': 'marketprice_aitp.predict', 
   'region': 'us-central1', 
   'runtimeVersion': '2.4', 
   , 
   'pythonVersion': '3.7', 
   'serviceAccount': 'projects/hh'}, 
  
  'createTime': '2021-11-08T06:49:34Z', 
  'startTime': '2021-11-08T07:07:33Z', 
  'endTime': '2021-11-08T07:07:33Z', 
  'state': 'SUCCEEDED', 
  'trainingOutput': {'consumedMLUnits': 0.09}, 
  'etag': '+YVkodd5cKA='}
```

I have a pandas dataframe which stores this output. And I am trying to access specific columns like belkow

```
df['region'] = df['trainingInput']["region"]
df['serviceaccount'] = df['trainingInput']["serviceAccount"]
```

I tried double quotes as well as

```
df['region'] = job[''''trainingInput''''][''''region''''']
df['serviceaccount'] = job[''''trainingInput''''][''''serviceAccount''''']
```

But I am getting key error. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: how does your dataframe look like? How do you convert the json to dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually manipulated my dataframe to convert that to correct dict format.

```
k_1  = df['trainingInput'].values
for i in k_1:
    m= json.dumps(i)
    k = json.loads(m)
    df['serviceaccount'] =k['serviceAccount']
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a single value at the intersection of a row/column. You an use `.at` here:

```
data = {'trainingInput': {'pythonModule': 'marketprice_aitp.predict', 
                        'region': 'us-central1', 'runtimeVersion': '2.4', 'pythonVersion': '3.7', 'serviceAccount': 'projects/hh'}, 
                    'createTime': '2021-11-08T06:49:34Z', 'startTime': '2021-11-08T07:07:33Z', 'endTime': '2021-11-08T07:07:33Z', 
                    'state': 'SUCCEEDED', 'trainingOutput': {'consumedMLUnits': 0.09}, 'etag': '+YVkodd5cKA='}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    
In [191]: df.at['region', 'trainingInput']

Out[191]: 'us-central1'

In [192]: df.at['serviceAccount', 'trainingInput']

Out[192]: 'projects/hh'
```

Comment: Thanks. But it did not work. The dataframe column 'trainingInput' is a pandas series in the format of

Comment: Thanks. But it did not work. The dataframe column 'trainingInput' is a pandas series in the format of Series([], Name: trainingInput, dtype: object)
0       {'scaleTier': 'CUSTOM', 'masterType': 'n2-high...
1       {'scaleTier': 'CUSTOM', 'masterType': 'n2-high....  . I am trying to convert the series into a dictionary and get the output using """for key, val in df["trainingInput"]:
        k_2[key] = val.apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(), axis=1).to_dict() """ . But that is giving me too many values to unpack error.

Comment: sample trainingInput data from the dataframe is:      [{'scaleTier': 'CUSTOM', 'masterType': 'n2-highmem-4', 'packageUris': ['/model_code/2021_11_10__01_51_12/marketprice_aitp-0.0.0.tar.gz'], 'pythonModule': 'marketprice', 'args': ['--env', 'prod', '--version', '4_1', '--bclgid', '10', '--clid', '102', '--as_of_date', '2021_11_09', '--event_id', '2021_11_10__01_51_12', '--user_project_id',  '--gbq_mpfull_data_location_staging', '--most_recent_train_job_dir'], 'region': 'us-central1', 'runtimeVersion': '2.4', 'jobDir': 'gs', 'pythonVersion': '3.7', 'serviceAccount': 'projects/hh'}]

Comment: since it looks like your data you provided in the example is different from what you have it's not possible to help. the api response provided parses easily to pandas so it's not clear why you have a something different. i suggest opening a different question and starting over with dataframe data, not the api response.